# Flutter desktop support custom file extension

Tags: flutter, desktop, file-extension

I am trying to **support a custom file extension** with my **flutter desktop app**.

I did not find anything on that and as I am from mobile development I have no idea how to do that for **MacOS and Windows** (Linux soon as it reaches stable).

Can you help me?

**This is what I want:** You click on an .abc file in your *Finder* or *Explorer* and the file should be opened in my Flutter desktop app.